# flutter:SCardTransmit was successful, but Idm cannot be retrieved

Tags: flutter, dart, nfc, smartcard, winscard

contents

```
int SCardTransmit(
        int hCard,
        Pointer<SCARD_IO_REQUEST> pioSendPci,
        Pointer<Uint8> pbSendBuffer,
        int cbSendLength,
        Pointer<SCARD_IO_REQUEST> pioRecvPci,
        Pointer<Uint8> pbRecvBuffer,
        Pointer<Uint32> pcbRecvLength)
```

The code I wrote

```
  int SCARD_PROTOCOL = 0;
  switch (pdwActiveProtocol.value) {
    case SCARD_PROTOCOL_T0:
      SCARD_PROTOCOL = SCARD_PROTOCOL_T0;
      break;
    case SCARD_PROTOCOL_T1:
      SCARD_PROTOCOL = SCARD_PROTOCOL_T1;
      break;
    default:
      print("Unknown protocol");
      break;
  }

  int hCard = phCard.value;
  List<int> data = [0xff, 0xca, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00];
  Uint8List bytes = Uint8List.fromList(data);
  Pointer<Uint8> pbSendBuffer = bytes.allocatePointer();
  Pointer<Uint8> pbRecvBuffer = calloc<Uint8>();
  int cbSendLength = bytes.length;
  Pointer<Uint32> pcbRecvLength = pbRecvBuffer.cast<Uint32>();

  Pointer<SCARD_IO_REQUEST> pioSendPci = calloc<SCARD_IO_REQUEST>()
    ..ref.cbPciLength = sizeOf<SCARD_IO_REQUEST>()
    ..ref.dwProtocol = SCARD_PROTOCOL;

  ret = SCardTransmit(hCard, pioSendPci, pbSendBuffer, cbSendLength, nullptr,
      pbRecvBuffer, pcbRecvLength);
```

This was successful, but I cannot get the UID. What is the problem?

I know there is something missing or wrong, but I don't know what it is.

What we use　：https://pub.dev/packages/win32

Card reader used: RC-380

add

```
Uint8List byte = pbRecvBuffer.asTypedList(pcbRecvLength.value);
1:[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 224, 159]
2:[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 204, 107]
```

Different from the first and second time.

Comment: I don't know what to put in the　pbRecvBuffer and pcbRecvLength

Comment: RecvBuffer is supposed to be a pointer to a buffer for the card response (typically different from the one containing the command sent), and RecvLength specifies its length. The latter one is overwritten with the actual number of bytes received.

Comment: Hi guidot!
Does that mean I can't get a UID?

Comment: I still haven't been able to solve the problem.
Please help me.

Comment: No idea, what you mean by UID. If you mean a unique card number, this is a sort of myth. You can come close to that, but it depends on what card you have and how it is personalized (because unique numbers can be represented as normal user data, where the issuer takess care of uniqeness). NFC is a term which is so broad to be useless to base an answer on it. The question provides no details on the NFC tag used (if you use one), I have little experience with devices of that limited capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

```
  int sendCommandToCard(int hCard, int SCARD_PROTOCOL, List<int> command) {
    Uint8List bytes = Uint8List.fromList(command);
    Pointer<Uint8> pbSendBuffer = bytes.allocatePointer();
    int cbSendLength = bytes.length;
    const int pbRecvBufferLength = 256; // 缓冲区长度
    Pointer<Uint8> pbRecvBuffer = Uint8List(pbRecvBufferLength).allocatePointer();
    Pointer<Uint32> pcbRecvLength = calloc<Uint32>();
    pcbRecvLength.value = pbRecvBufferLength;

    Pointer<SCARD_IO_REQUEST> pioSendPci = calloc<SCARD_IO_REQUEST>()
      ..ref.cbPciLength = sizeOf<SCARD_IO_REQUEST>()
      ..ref.dwProtocol = SCARD_PROTOCOL;

    int retCode = SCardTransmit(hCard, pioSendPci, pbSendBuffer, cbSendLength, nullptr, pbRecvBuffer, pcbRecvLength);
    if (retCode == SCARD_S_SUCCESS) {
      Uint8List byte = pbRecvBuffer.asTypedList(pcbRecvLength.value);
      debugPrint("SCardTransmit - result:$retCode lenght:${pcbRecvLength.value} byte:$byte");
    }
    return retCode;
  }
```